# Behind ISP NAT Firewall - Need to remotely monitor CCTV's

Tags: nat, remote-access, video-streaming

Here's my situation:
I have a DVR which is capable of allowing me to remotely view my shop CCTV's over IP.However, I'm behind the ISP's NAT firwall and have no ability to open ports on the router, so I'm stuck to an IP range of 192.168.xxx.xxx
For this reason, I cannot use this feature to remotely view my shop.

I'm now thinking of putting up a Linux machine connected with atleast 2 web cams, but really have no idea of how I can access them through this NAT firewall situation.

P2P?

Or in a scenario like this would reverse SSH tunneling help? I know I have setup reverse SSH tunnel for a headless linux server which I can manage remotely, but not sure if this can be a solution here.

Comment: I would use IPv6, then you can avoid NAT. (Should you happen to have bought a CCTV without IPv6 support, then ask the vendor for a firmware updated). (Should you happen to have bought an internet connection without IPv6 support, then configure a tunnel and ask the ISP what they have been doing for the last 16 years).

Comment: the issue we face is, that ISP control things alot here - no IPv6, no public IP's & no discussions. A take it or leave it attitude. That's why I'm so stuck and need to find an alternative.

Comment: Find a competing ISP. If there is no competing ISP, then it sucks to be you, but you can still use a tunnel. There are free IPv6 tunnel providers which can provide service, even if your ISP can't provide you a proper service. IPv6 is the only long term solution to your problem, and using a tunnel may be the only way you can move towards a solution.